# how can i change my wordpress pagination url for blog page?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages

I have pagination url in wordpress for blog page like

"https://website.com/blog/page/2"

want to change it to

"https://website.com/blog/page-2"

where blog is page name for blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can head over to the following link -> [Function Reference/paginate links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)
 In your case you should take a look at the `format` value and set it accordingly as per your requirements.